# How to send Post request to stripe in quarkus

Tags: kotlin, post, stripe-payments, quarkus

i am tring to use REST api for stripe payment link creation using quarkus and kotlin.
i tried to pass the parameters exactly like the CURL request and i tried to pass them as 'price' and 'quantity' but did not work. on this provided code i am getting 415 unsupported media type on postman (i set the content-type to application/x-www-from-urlencoded). on some edition of code i am getting 400 bad request also (often missing parameter as i know).
here is some of my code :
StripCaller :

```
data class CreatePaymentLinkRequest(
@FormParam("line_items[0][price]")
val lineItemPrice: String,

@FormParam("line_items[0][quantity]")
val lineItemQuantity: Int
)

    @Path("/payment_links")
    @RegisterRestClient(configKey = "stripe-link")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    interface StripeCaller {
        @POST
        fun createPaymentLink(
            request: CreatePaymentLinkRequest,
            @HeaderParam("Authorization") authorizationHeader: String
        ): PaymentLinkList
    
    }

    @Path("/payments")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
class PaymentController {
    @Inject
    @RestClient
    internal lateinit var stripeCaller: StripeCaller

    val secretKey = "sk_test_51NX-XXX-XXXX"

    @POST

    fun createPaymentLink(
        request: CreatePaymentLinkRequest
    ): Response {
        val authorizationHeader = secretKey
        val link = stripeCaller.createPaymentLink(request, authorizationHeader)

        // Process the response, store paymentLink ID in DB, etc.
        return Success(data = link).respond()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stripe's API expects the content-type to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for form data, but the `@Consumes` annotation on your `StripeCaller` interface is set to `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`.

To fix this, you can remove the `@Consumes` annotation from the `StripeCaller` interface and set the content-type explicitly in your `createPaymentLink` method, like this:

```
interface StripeCaller {
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun createPaymentLink(
        @HeaderParam("Authorization") authorizationHeader: String,
        @HeaderParam("Content-Type") contentType: String,
        request: CreatePaymentLinkRequest
    ): PaymentLinkList
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but unfortunately I am still getting the same error. i did specify the Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded  exactly.